# Is there any free geo database?

Tags: geolocation

I want to build an location based application,
and I don't know how to get some location data, like:
the latitude and longitude of nearby starbucks, KFC, or pizza?

Is there any free database on the internet?
how does others get those data? like yelp, foursquare?

Comment: Which geographic region are you interested in? USA?

Answer (score 3):

[Openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) has quite a few POI in their database i think, check out their rendered map if it does contain the info you need.

Oh, and you need around 100GB for the full db :)